# Capture and broadcast video from web cam

Tags: debian, video, camera, video-encoding, broadcast

I have server on Debian 6, without Desktop Environment and I have simple web camera. Web camera is defined like `/dev/video0`, so I can use `cat /dev/video0 > ~/photo` to get image from it (of course this is not correct way :))

I want to capture, convert and broadcast video stream by HTTP, or can I make common IP web cam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this using [motion](http://www.lavrsen.dk/foswiki/bin/view/Motion/WebHome)

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/index.html); it has packages available for most distros, including [Debian](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-debian.html).

Comment: Perhaps you could improve your answer by showing how to do this with VLC.